# What happens if in the genesis file, I put something different than 0(0x0) for the "number" property?

Tags: blocks, genesis

From what I have understood, the `number` property from the genesis file represents the block number (to match block structure). So, logically, it should be `0x0` because the genesis file is the first block (block 0).

What would happen if I put something else ? Would the initialization of the chain fail ? Would the chain start at block X ?

Comment: Which number are you talking about? Is this for a private network or main chain?

Comment: @SamuelDare I am talking about a private network. I am talking about a property number that some guys at my company did put in the genesis file.

Comment: can you share a snippet of it? I cant grok `property` number,. Are you refereing to the EIP activations?

Comment: @SamuelDare here is a gist with the genesis: https://gist.github.com/floriancastelain/5a6a4a4fea96033ed9b0c6ba15cba54a